# Alpinejs Event Listener On Checkbox Not Toggling Show Variable Value

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, events, alpine.js

I'm working with Alpinejs and Laravel and I wanted to show a hidden input field when a checkbox is checked.

So here it is:

```
<div x-data="{ show:false }">
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1" name="change_background" @click="show = event.target.value == 'on' ? true : false">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                Change Background
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-3" x-show="show">
        <label for="background" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Background File</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="file" name="background" id="background">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So if user checks the checkbox (*Change Background*), then the file input field would be appear.

So I tried binding the value to `show` variable:

```
@click="show = event.target.value == 'on' ? true : false">
```

Now the problem with this is that, when I uncheck the checkbox once again to hide the file upload field, it still appears on the page somehow.

So what's going wrong here? How can I toggle this field depending on the value of checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of a checkbox is `on`. Therefore `event.target.value == 'on'` is always `true`, so `show` will be always `true` after the first click.

The fix is very easy, just use the [`x-model` directive](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/model#single-checkbox-with-boolean) to bind the boolean value of `show` to the checkbox:

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
<div x-data="{ show:false }">
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1" x-model="show">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
        Change Background
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mb-3" x-show="show">
    <label for="background" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Background File</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="file" name="background" id="background">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```